# Не работает скрипт

Tags: ajax, javascript

по нажатию кнопки запускается JS скрипт который отправляет пост запрос используя `ajax` и полученный ответ выводит на экран, но сего не происходит. Где может быть ошибка?
Файл `ajax.js`:

```
 function send()
 {

 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://www.samair.ru/s-proxychecker/index.php",
data: $("#proxyForm").serialize(),

success: function(html) 
{
 $("#result").html(html);
 }
});
}
```

Сам html файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jQuery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction()
{

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=document.getElementById('text').value;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="proxyForm">
    <input type="text" name="proxy" />
    <input type="text" name="time" />
    <input type="text" name="go" />

</form>
<input type="button" onclick="send();" value="Отправить" />
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почему не работает - вам ответили ниже, а я бы посоветовал вам попробовать использовать **cURL** для этой задачи.

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка может быть в том, что [кроссдоменные запросы запрещены](http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#контроль-безопасности) на samair.ru. В консоль-то смотрели? [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/azojod/1/) для проверки.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> http://www.samair.ru/s-proxychecker/index.php.
> Origin http://jsbin.com is not allowed
> by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1):

И не будет работать.
т.к. предполагаю ты POST запрос делаешь на удаленный хост, что запрещено политикой.